# Meaning and difference of the word faite vs faîte

Tags: sens

What does "faite" mean?

What does "faîte" mean?

What is the difference between the two if any?

Is there any cultural significance?

Does either word have any slang or connotations associated?

What does each word make someone feel?  Is it just a basic everyday word or is one rarely used or for a special occasion?

Answer (score 2):

A simple dictionary look [Dictionnaire Larousse :](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fa%C3%AEte/32734#definition)

Faîte (et faite orthographe rectifiée)

> Arête supérieure d'une toiture. Synonyme de faîtage. Partie la plus
>   élevée d'un relief, de quelque chose ; sommet, cime : Le faîte des
>   montagnes.
>
> **Littéraire**. Degré le plus élevé de quelque chose : Arriver au faîte des honneurs.
>   Mots de la même famille : faîtage, faîteau, faîtier et faîtière.

See also : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fa%C3%AEte

1. What does "faite" mean? See above and [1](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fa%C3%AEte/32734#definition) below.
2. What does "faîte" mean? Ibid.
3. What is the difference between the two if any? Rectified orthographe admits the former (without the accent).
4. Is there any cultural significance? The only one I see, not being a native speaker though, is that despite that the so-called rectified orthographe dates from 1990, is not still accepted by everyone:-)!
5. Does either word have any slang or connotations associated? No as far I know.

[1](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fa%C3%AEte/32734#definition) Note there is also faite**s** of faire; that is, vous faites (and no vous faisez a common mistake among beginners ). Also, there is also the past participle of faire when one needs to make the feminine accord. E.g. Cette bague est faite en or.

Comment: Thank you.  I do know that faite (without accent) is past participle of faire which means 'do/make' so faite would mean 'did/made' so very common for people to use in everyday communication.

Faîte (with accent) is where I wasn't sure how it was used if at all for native French speakers. When I do a google translate for faîte I get back words like ridge or top/haut/summit/zenith/apogee etc so sounds like that may be how it could be interpreted although it doesn't sound like there is a definitive answer because it isn't used commonly.  Maybe used to say the top of something.